# Is it possible to use external libraries in the dialogflow inline editor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm using the Dialogflow inline editor and I was wondering if it was possible to use external libraries?

For example, I was looking to use the Twilio programmable SMS to send an SMS when a certain intent was triggered. I noticed they have their own node.js library which makes what I want to do super simple.

- I assume if this isn't possible then the next best would be using the Actions SDK and using external libraries?

Is this possible?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dialogflow's inline editor, you can go to the package.json tab to add additional libraries.

Here's a few other notes:

- Dialogflow uses cloud functions for firebase, so you can develop and deploy using a more familiar environment instead.
- Cloud functions by default will be on the free plan, which blocks external API calls. Upgrading to the pay-as-you-go plan will remove this restriction.